# How to redirect button in express using specific mongodb _id as paremeter

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to update my data in MongoDB using the `_id` field, this is the HTML button to do so:

```html
<form action="/update/:_id" method="get" id="edit-button">
  <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="edit-button">
    Edit Post
  </button>
</form>
```

This is the code for my Express server `app.js`:

```js
app.get('/update/:_id', function (req, res) {
  const updateId = req.params._id;
  Post.findOne({ _id: updateId })
    .then((Posts) => {
      res.render('update', {
        updatedTitle: Posts.title,
        updatedContent: Posts.content,
        id: updateId,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
});

app.post('/update', function (req, res) {
  // const updateId = req.params.updateId;
  const updatedTitle = req.body.updatedTitle;
  const updatedContent = req.body.updatedContent;
  const updateId = req.body.id;

  post
    .findByIdAndUpdate(
      { _id: updateId },
      {
        title: updatedTitle,
        content: updatedContent,
      }
    )
    .then(() => res.redirect('/'));
});
```

This is the code for my view template `update.ejs`:

```js
<form action="/update" method="get">
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="titleInput" class="form-label">Title</label>
    <input
      type="text"
      class="form-control"
      name="updatedTitle"
      value="<%= updatedTitle %>"
      required
    />
  </div>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="postArea" class="form-label">Post</label>
    <textarea
      class="form-control"
      rows="5"
      name="updatedPost"
      value="<%= updatedContent %>"
      required
    ><%= updatedContent %></textarea>
  </div>
  <button
    class="btn btn-primary update"
    type="submit"
    name="id"
    value="<%= id %>"
  >
    Update
  </button>
</form>
```

It works fine when I try to acceesing the link directly. For example: `http://localhost:3000/update/644a6d4c6fbe854da2375c61`. However, when I try to press the button or fiddling with the code it gives one of the following errors:

> Cannot GET /update

Or in console:

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value ":_id" (type string) at
path "_id" for model "Post" and BSONError: Argument passed in must be
a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer
```